# How can I tell if an image is touching the top of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I want to make my menu disappear and some other actions happen once an image hits the top of the screen as I scroll.  The images are full width, so they hit every point on the x-axis.  I have tried using elementFromPoint, but that just returns me the entire html document.  Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Tools of the trade: jQuery's `.offset()`, `.scrollTop()` and `.scroll()`.

Comment: Try [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/jquery-zepto/), it lets trigger events when you scroll to elements.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming your image is fixed (which I think it is), then you can do this:**

```js
    var timer;
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        // Set a timeout so that the function doesn't
        // execute at every scroll event.
        // Only when the user has actually stopped scrolling
        if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            if($('#hello').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() <= 0) {
                $('#hello').attr('alt', 'Im touching the top!');
                $('#status').text('Image is touching the top, or past it');
            } else {
              $('#hello').attr('alt', 'Not at top');
              $('#status').text('Image is not touching the top');
            }
        }, 100);
    });
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 400%;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#status {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status">Image is not touching the top</div>
<img id="hello" alt="I'm an image">
```

Comment: Thanks!  I need to know when any part of the image is touching the top though, not just when it hits the top.  My image is also block.

Comment: Aaah, I think I get what you mean. I've updated the code, is this what you want? If not, can you provide an explanation/picture of what you want or sample of your code?